# Pushing data into object clears the other values

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm making trying to push data into an object, but as soon as I push data to `userID.name`, the value of `userID.age` gets reset(?) in the console. Here's my code:

```
if (input.indexOf("ben") >= 0){
    var slot = splitInput.indexOf("ben");
    console.log(slot)
    i = slot + 1;

    if (splitInput[i].indexOf(0) >= 0 || splitInput[i].indexOf(1) >= 0 || splitInput[i].indexOf(3) >= 0 || splitInput[i].indexOf(4) >= 0 || splitInput[i].indexOf(4) >= 0 || splitInput[i].indexOf(5) >= 0 || splitInput[i].indexOf(6) >= 0 || splitInput[i].indexOf(7) >= 0 || splitInput[i].indexOf(8) >= 0 || splitInput[i].indexOf(9) >= 0){
        i = 0;
        var slot = splitInput.indexOf("ben");
        // console.log(slot)
        i = slot + 1;
        userID.age = splitInput[i];
        console.log(userID);

    } if (splitInput[i].indexOf("a") >= 0 || splitInput[i].indexOf("e") >= 0 || splitInput[i].indexOf("i") >= 0 || splitInput[i].indexOf("u") >= 0){
        i = 0;
        var slot = splitInput.indexOf("ben");
        // console.log(slot)
        i = slot + 1;
        userID.name = splitInput[i];
        console.log(userID);
    }
}
```

Here's my `splitInput`:

```
var splitInput = input.split(" ");
```

input is gathered through a `getElementById` function.

When I manually log `userID` I get this error `VM935:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: userID is not defined(…)` which may have something to do with it, although `console.log(userID)` works fine.

If you need more information, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Format your code so that it's readable. Also, make sure it is the minimal code that **demonstrates** your problem, not necessarily your exact code.

Comment: when you manually log? what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before assigning to an object property, like `UserID.age`, you must first have defined `UserID` itself.

So put this before you access a property of `UserID`:

```
var userID = {};
```

#### Remarks on the code

The way you check for numbers and words with vowels is not really that nice. It has a lot of repetitive code. Also inside the `if` blocks you were searching again for the word "ben", while you had that already done... Seems unnecessary to do that again.

Have a look at this version of your code:

```js
// Sample data
var input = 'ik ben 51 jaar';

var splitInput = input.split(" ");
// This was missing:
var userID = {};
// Move retrieval of slot before the `if` so it can be reused
var slot = splitInput.indexOf("ben");
if (slot >= 0){
    console.log('slot:', slot);
    i = slot + 1;
    // Make sure you are not at the end of the array, and 
    // use a regular expression to see next word consists of digits only
    if (i < splitInput.length && splitInput[i].match(/^\d+$/)){
        // convert the word to number with unitary plus:
        userID.age = +splitInput[i];
    } 
    // You'll maybe want to do an else here.
    // Use regular expression again; don't forget the "o"
    else if (i < splitInput.length && splitInput[i].match(/a|e|i|o|u/)){
        userID.name = splitInput[i];
    }
    console.log(userID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I was looking for. I know my if where a little messy, but the /^\d+$/ thing didn't work out really well, but now it does. Thanks again